# Slow processing of a huge dataset in Talend

Tags: java, talend

I am pulling data from a SQL Server stored procedure using tMSSqlSP which is returning results in RECORD SET format. After this, I am parsing the record set and using a tMap and then inserting the record in to an Oracle table using tOracleOutput.

Processing is very slow (30 records per second).

The SQL Server stored procedure returns 500k records and this slow processing takes ages to complete.

Is anyone aware of the process to make insertion faster on Oracle side?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your job layout please? Also include screenshots of the configuration of any key components such as the tMap and the tOracleOutput. It might be interesting for you to benchmark the data being returned from the stored procedure as well rather than looking at just the inserting to the Oracle database.

Comment: Thanks for the response, do you know when SQLServer procedure returns RESULT SET in Talend, does it return all the data at once in memory, or it will pull each record individually?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will return a single object that then gets parsed later but I don't have any experience with SQL Server sprocs in Talend. Is there any reason you can't have your sproc return variables? Talend can use these as OUT parameters and should be able to stream the data (assuming you have nothing in your job flow that would require the data to be gathered such as a tSortRow). It's hard to say without seeing what your job looks like though.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If so, it might be worth self answering to help others who might run into the same problem. If not, could you provide more detailed information about your job including screenshots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have to use bulk insertion in oracle : tOracleOutputBulk component.
It's more complex to configure but if you insert in one table with no transaction it's a powerfull solution.